# Estou com um problema no Ionic3

Tags: ionic

Estou aprendendo a usar o Ionic, como exemplo para isso estou a seguir um curso. criei uma intro com 3 slides que no final criei um "Click" para ir a Tabs, com Home e feed, porem o Feed parou de funcionar, quando clico não vai mais

Feed.html

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->

Feed

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="assets/imgs/avatar.png">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2 class="feed_title">{{ nome_usuario }}</h2>
  <p class="feed_descr">November 5, 1955</p>
</ion-item>

<img src="assets/imgs/advance-card-bttf.png">

<ion-card-content>
  <p>Programar em Ionic é perfeito.</p>
</ion-card-content>

<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <button ion-button icon-start clear small>
      <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
      <div>12 Likes</div>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <button ion-button icon-start clear small>
      <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
      <div>4 Comments</div>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col center text-center>
    <ion-note>
      11h ago
    </ion-note>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { FeedPage } from '../feed/feed';
import { IntroPage } from '../intro/intro';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = FeedPage;
  tab3Root = IntroPage;
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

arquivos diferentes

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Feed" tabIcon="ios-paper-outline"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

arquivos diferentes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the FeedPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-feed',
  templateUrl: 'feed.html',
})
export class FeedPage {
  public nome_usuario:string = "Wesley Israel App";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  public somadoisnumeros(num1:number, num2:number): void{
    alert(num1 + num2);

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    //this.somadoisnumeros(12, 5);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Ionic 3 usa lazy loading para carregar páginas, o que ajuda a melhorar o tempo de abertura do aplicativo. Estou vendo pelo código da página Feed que você criou apelo Ionic, provavelmente pela linha de comando, usando `ionic g page feed`. Portanto, você precisará chamar a página não pelo componente, mas pelo nome (string). No arquivo feed.module.ts, acrescente o seguinte:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  ],
  exports: [
    FeedPage
  ]
```

No arquivo tabs.ts, altere `tab2Root = FeedPage;` para `tab2Root = "FeedPage";`.